# How do you get this div to wrap around an image link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, positioning

I have this image link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image" %>
```

and I want to wrap a div containing 1. text and 2. a list with a link and text around that image link. I want the image to be on the left, and the div to be on the right wrapping around the image.

[image]

Comment: screenshot of what you need to do?

Comment: sorry for the bad image quality... also ignore the weird test comments lol

Comment: so the text and the footer (the small link and text below the comment text) should be wrapping around the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need any of the fancier features offered by the `link_to` helper, the easy answer is to just use an anchor tag directly.

```
<a href="<%= profile_path(comment.user.profile) %> class="comment_image">
  <div>
    Some stuff -- whatever
    <%= image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)) %>
    Some more stuff -- ya know...
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use the link_to helper

Comment: You can make this work, using the link helper, but the code will be uglier and harder to maintain.  It's adding another layer of abstraction for no particularly good reason.  Nevertheless, you can concatenate text strings containing literal HTML by using the `html_safe` method on each literal string. "<sometag>...".html_safe.

Comment: and then I just float the div and .comment_image to the left?

Comment: yeah float them both to the left

Answer (score 0):

would you care if i posted it in HAML(same thing as erb just without the `<% %>` and closing tags:(sort of pseudo code for html)

```
%ul
  %li
    = link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image"
    %div.user-comments
      comment
      username etc

  %li
    rinse-repeat
```

AND dont forget to clear your float on the li!

then in your css, just float comment_image and user-comments left.